# LexikjwtAuthenticator Symfony define route for authentication

Tags: symfony, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to use Lexikjwtauthenticator on a Symfony project but I cannot figure out where is the /api/login_check Controller defined.

I'm receiving "Unable to find the controller for path "/api/login_check". The route is wrongly configured." all the times.
The only way to work around this is to define a form_login (other than json_login) configuration inside the login firewall. Is it correct or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Unable to find the controller for path because endpoint for login_check is only /login_check not api/login_check

Comment: you should have it defined in config/routes.yaml

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the real problem was caused by using "postman" which apparently sends data as "form" instead of "json".

Modifying security.yaml "json_login" and replacing it with "form_login" (which is documented) everything seems to work fine with Postman.

I still have to try it from my JS front-end.

Comment: Glad you are making progress.  Be aware that there is no login_check controller as such.  Instead there are security event listeners which sort of act as controllers.  They intercept the login_check request, do the authentication and then direct the appropriate response.

Comment: That's why I couldn't find the controller. I was not able to find that inside the documentation... Maybe it was just me.Thanks